# Unable to fetch YouTube Insights for some accounts

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

For specific accounts, we are able to fetch data but not able to fetch reporting analytics, I am getting

> error  {   "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "Forbidden",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Forbidden",
> "domain": "global",
> "reason": "forbidden"
> }
> ]   } }

Account has permissions for accessing reports. But for accounts with same permissions, we are able to fetch insights

API Endpoint: https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports

> API Request:
> https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?access_token=xxxxxxx&dimensions=day&metrics=views%2CredViews%2Ccomments%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2CvideosAddedToPlaylists%2CvideosRemovedFromPlaylists%2Cshares%2CestimatedMinutesWatched%2CestimatedRedMinutesWatched%2CaverageViewDuration%2CaverageViewPercentage%2CannotationClickThroughRate%2CannotationCloseRate%2CannotationImpressions%2CannotationClickableImpressions%2CannotationClosableImpressions%2CannotationClicks%2CannotationCloses%2CcardClickRate%2CcardTeaserClickRate%2CcardImpressions%2CcardTeaserImpressions%2CcardClicks%2CcardTeaserClicks%2CsubscribersGained%2CsubscribersLost%2CestimatedRevenue%2CestimatedAdRevenue%2CgrossRevenue%2CestimatedRedPartnerRevenue%2CmonetizedPlaybacks%2CplaybackBasedCpm%2CadImpressions%2Ccpm&ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&startDate=2020-06-10&endDate=2020-07-09

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I have recently answered a similar question, which you might find worthwhile reading...

Comment: I got solution. This error was because of some deprecated metrics. I removed them and it started working.